# Imported js files inside site.js not loading on frontend (asp.net core mvc)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, import, static-files

_Layout.cshmtl

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true" ></script>
```

site.js

```
import NotificationCore from "../lib/core/modules/notification-module";
import AjaxLoader from "../lib/core/modules/ajax-loader";

new NotificationCore()
new AjaxLoader()
```

[imported files inside site.js not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9wS2.png)

app.UseStaticFiles inside program.cs is written, everything is fine, for some reason it is the imported files that are not loaded

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add `.js`, try to change your code like below:

```
import NotificationCore from "../lib/core/modules/notification-module.js";
import AjaxLoader from "../lib/core/modules/ajax-loader.js";

new NotificationCore()
new AjaxLoader()
```